# Algoritmo para solução de Fuga com Helicóptero

Tags: algoritmo

Recentemente consegui resolver um problema algorítmico enumerando todas as possíveis condições. Porém, acredito que através de algum artifício matemático, seria possível resolver o problema de forma mais simples.

O problema pode ser visto aqui: https://neps.academy/problem/5

> Um fugitivo, um helicóptero e um policial estão em posições distintas numa pista circular, exatamente como a mostrada na figura ao lado, com dezesseis posições numeradas de 0 a 15 em direção anti-horária. O helicóptero e o policial ficam sempre parados. O objetivo do fugitivo é chegar no helicóptero sem passar pelo policial antes, claro. Ele pode decidir correr na direção horária, ou na direção anti-horária. Neste problema, dadas as posições do helicóptero, do policial e do fugitivo, e a direção em que o fugitivo decide correr, seu programa deve dizer se ele vai ou não conseguir fugir! Na figura, se o fugitivo decidir correr na direção horária, ele consegue fugir; se decidir correr na direção anti-horária, ele vai ser preso antes de chegar no helicóptero!
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> **Entrada**
>
> A entrada consiste de uma linha com quatro inteiros: *H, P, F* e *D*, representando, respectivamente, as posições do helicóptero, do policial e do fugitivo, e a direção em que o fugitivo corre, −1 para horário e 1 para anti-horário.
>
> **Saída**
>
> Seu programa deve imprimir uma linha contendo o caracter "S" se o fugitivo consegue fugir, ou "N" caso contrário
>
> **Restrições**
>
> Os inteiros H, P e F são distintos e estão entre 0 e 15, inclusive

A intenção deste post é discutir alguma forma mais fácil de resolver o problema em questão... Por favor, não é necessário compartilhar o código de resolução. Responder a pergunta com a solução mencionada (enumerar todas as condições) também não vale :P

PS.: Se este post não for adequado para o fórum, já peço desculpa e se necessário, posso remove-lo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta analisar matematicamente (equacionar) e verificar qual está mais próximo.

Digamos que o fugitivo precisa caminhar `p` posições para chegar até o policial e `h` posições para chegar até o helicóptero. Assim:

- P = F + D*p
- H = F + D*h

Como conhecemos as posições de cada um, podemos calcular quantas posições esses valores representam:

- p = (P - F)/D
- h = (H - F)/D

O número que representar a menor quantidade de posições indicará quem está mais perto naquela direção e, portanto, o fugitivo fugirá se `h < p`.

Dado o exemplo, `F = 7`, `H = 4`, `P = 14` e `D = -1`, assim:

- p = (14 - 7)/(-1) = -7
- h = (4 - 7)/(-1) = 3

A saída esperada é `S`, indicando que `h` deveria ser menor, mas `p` é menor. Isso acontece porque a equação resulta no menor número de posições que o fugitivo deve andar até chegar ao outro ponto. Sendo negativo significa que ele contrariaria a premissa da direção dada como entrada. Isto é, o fugitivo teria que andar 7 posições na direção a que foi definida por `D`. Portanto, não podemos considerar um valor negativo; sempre um positivo. Para calcular o complemento do valor negativo obtido, basta adicionar 16, que é a quantidade total de posições.

Assim, `p`, que foi calculado como -7, passa a ser 9. Comparando `p = 9` e `h = 3`, obtemos que nessa configuração o helicóptero estará mais próximo e, portanto, o fugitivo fugirá com sucesso.

---

Em questão de código (Python), ficaria:

```
def fuga(H, P, F, D):
    h = (H - F)/D
    p = (P - F)/D

    h += 16 if h < 0 else 0
    p += 16 if p < 0 else 0

    return 'S' if h < p else 'N'
```

Se o valor calculado originalmente for negativo (para ambos os valores), será acrescentado 16. Se `h` for menor que `p`, a fuga será bem sucedida.

O número de operações que esta solução executa não depende dos valores de entrada, configurando, assim, uma solução de complexidade O(1).

```
testes = [
    (4, 14, 7, -1, 'S'),
    (4, 14, 7, 1, 'N'),
    (15, 9, 8, -1, 'S'),
    (0, 14, 15, -1, 'N')
]

for teste in testes:
    H, P, F, D, resultado = teste
    assert resultado == fuga(H, P, F, D), f'O teste {teste} falhou'
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FixedDeliciousBrace)</sup>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa! Era isso que eu não tava conseguindo formular :) Valeu Anderson :D